# how to debug requests with a client certificate C#

Tags: c#, https, fiddler, client-certificates

I am currently trying to make a secure request (HTTPS) via client certificate, but I'm having issues understanding if the client is actually sending the certificate itself.

I already tried fiddler for checking the traffic, but I was not able to find any filter or any doc about it (and the official docs of fiddler seems also down atm)

Cheers in advance

Comment: You have to look at the http headers to find issues.  I usually compare a good result using an IE with the failed results using HttpRequest.  Http uses TCP as transport layer.  Each Http message has a status of 200 Done when complete.   Errors will show up with various error status codes. TCP has max datagram of ~1500.  So each Http message consists of multiple TCP packets. HTTPS is secure and uses multiple TCP ports and uses a Proxy Server to get Certificate.

Answer (score 1):

As far, I know you cannot use fiddler because it captures only HTTP(S) traffic, but SSL negotiation happens on transport (TCP) level. You can use [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) traffic analyzer and [this guide](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/nettracer/2013/12/30/how-it-works-on-the-wire-iis-http-client-certificate-authentication/) or [this](http://www.moserware.com/2009/06/first-few-milliseconds-of-https.html).